# SqlBase Database on One Drive

Tags: sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper

I have a database on "Microsoft OneDrive", I have 4 valid licenses from Gupta 4 SqlBase.  When I try to run from PC 1 I can access the database, but when I try the same from PC 2 I got this

Reason: Attempting to open an existing file and a failure has occurred.
      Remedy: Determine and correct the cause of the open file failure.
       Verify that the specified file exists.  Verify the number of
       files allowed open for the operating system permits the
       additional file, that is, check the FILES= configuration
       parameter setting.

I assume this is related to the LOG files on the database and some settings in the Sql.Ini, but I'm not able to find where/how???

The intention is to run the database on "OneDrive", buy SqlBase licenses and run a multi user system.  The application has been made as such.

Where do I think wrong?
Where do I do wrong?
What setting are missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.
SqlBase (and all other RDBMS) are built to manage one databasefile + logfiles.
When multiple instances work with more or less replicated datafiles this ends up in a clash.
There are systems in the world which can work as a distributed cluster (e.g. like the document-database RavenDB) but they are built to work like this (not with OneDrive of course but with their own replication mechanism). Sqlbase is not.